# Tags trigger not working in azure pipelines

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the exact same pipeline in two different branches of the same repository, `stage` and `prod`.

I'd like the pipeline on branch `stage` to run when a tag starting with `stage@` is created (e.g. `stage@1.0.1`); similarly, I'd like the pipeline on branch `prod` to run when a tag starting with `prod@` is created (e.g. `prod@1.0.1`).

In branch `stage`, trigger is defined like this:

```yaml
# .azure-pipelines.yml [refs/branches/stage]

trigger:
  tags:
    include:
      - stage@*
```

In branch `prod`, trigger is defined like this:

```yaml
# .azure-pipelines.yml [refs/branches/prod]

trigger:
  tags:
    include:
      - prod@*
```

Now I created a pipeline on Azure DevOps named `[Deploy to STAGE]` from the file in the `stage` branch, and one named `[Deploy to PROD]` from the file in the `prod` branch.

I tried creating a tag:

```sh
$ git branch
  master
  prod
* stage

$ git tag -a stage@1.0.6 -m "stage@1.0.6"
$ git push --tags
```

I expected the `[Deploy to STAGE]` pipeline to start, but both pipelines started instead:

[image]

Am I missing something? Isn't the trigger supposed to only include tags matching the defined pattern? How do I correct the trigger to achieve the described flow?

Comment: Am I right when I say that you use the same file on both branches?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej Yes. Could it be the cause? It would be weird though, because when creating a pipeline DevOps asks for both the file name and the branch, so it would be weird for it to just ignore the branch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two pipelines `Deploy to STAGE` and `Deploy to Prod` are two identical pipelines. Though you choose the file from branch `Prod` when creating pipeline `Deploy to Prod`, this pipeline will apply to `Stage` branch too. This is because both the pipelines use the same azure-pipelines.yml file and this file exists on both stage and prod branch.

From the screenshot of the build runs, You can see the two pipelines were building the exact same stage tag. If you add a tag to `prod` branch, you will see both the pipeline will be triggered too.

Actually you only need to create either one of the two pipelines. Both of they will apply to prod and stage branch. So you can just delete pipeline `Deploy to Prod`. When you push a tag to prod branch. You will notice the pipeline `Deploy to STAGE` is building the prod tag.

If you have to create two pipelines. You need to rename the azure-pipelines.yml file in `prod` branch or create a new yml file with the some contents and with a different name. And create pipeline `Deploy to PROD` from this new yml file.

If you choose to create a new yml file to create pipeline `Deploy to PROD`, you need to disable the trigger (`trigger: none`) in the original azure-pipelines.yml file in prod branch, so that pipeline `Deploy to Stage` will not be triggered to build prod tag when tag is pushed to prod branch.

In summary, if you want to create different pipelines for different branches, you will have to create different pipeline yml files.

Comment: It's really weird that DevOps asks for the filename and the branch when creating a pipeline and then ignores the branch when executing it. I will try changing the filename,

Comment: Hi, so sorry for the late response. This was it indeed, after changing the file names to `.azure-pipelines.stage.yml` and `.azure-pipelines.prod.yml` triggers started working correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce you case but I couldn't manage to get the same result.

So for pipeline in `stage`

```yaml
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
      - stage@*

steps:
- powershell: Write-Host "stage"
```

and pipeline in `prod`

```yaml
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
      - prod@*

steps:
- powershell: Write-Host "prod"
```

I got this:

[image]

However, I would recommend you different approach as this could prone to error as on merging both branches you always need to have in mind to do not touch this files. Create two separate branches one with trigger for stage tag and one with trigger for prod tag. Extract common stuff to template and if some arguments in tasks are different please make them as parameters in template.
About templates you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops).