# How do I set up different pipelines for each branch in Azure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a single project but with two "master" branches.

- master
- virt/master

Each of them would have their own `azure-pipeline.yml` specific for their branch.

The first pipeline in `master` has the trigger set up as

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - refs/heads/master
```

The second one is  in the `virt/master` branch.

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - refs/heads/virt/master
```

Here's the repository that I am experimenting on https://dev.azure.com/trajano/experiments/_git/multi-branch

- `master` build https://dev.azure.com/trajano/experiments/_build?definitionId=11
- `virt/master` build https://dev.azure.com/trajano/experiments/_build?definitionId=12

The problem I am having is when I push a change to the `virt/master` branch both pipelines get executed

[image]

Am I missing something in my configuration?  Or is this a bug on Azure Devops?

I also tried to exclude but to no avail.

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - refs/heads/master
    exclude:
      - refs/heads/virt/master
```

Comment: Perhaps this will clear things up for you: They should both use the **same** pipeline. When a pipeline is triggered, it will use the version of the file *in the branch that's being built*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create different pipelines for different branches. You need to rename the azure-pipelines.yml file in `virt/master` branch or create a new yml file with the some contents and with a **different name**. And create pipeline `multi-branch(virt)` from this new yml file.

If both pipelines are created from the yaml file with the same name azure-pipeline.yml. And the azure-pipeline.yml file exists in both of the branches. Then they are identical pipelines(`even though the azure-pipeline.yml file contents might be different`).

You can see from above screen. Pipeline `multi-branch` and `multi-branch(virt)` were building the same `virt/master` branch(`using the tasks in the azure-pipeline.yml of virt/master`). If you push to master branch. You will see both pipelines will be triggered to build master branch(`using the tasks in the azure-pipeline.yml of master`). Pipeline `multi-branch` and `multi-branch(virt)` are one pipeline

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64569496/tags-trigger-not-working-in-azure-pipelines/64585112#64585112) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have separate pipelines please create separate file definition for them. I think that your configuration is fine and the issue is that you share the same file as definition.

When I moved to separate file it works as expected:

[image]